# About wp database hooks (error establishing connection)

Tags: database, hooks, wpdb

Is there a hook, which is being called immediately after/before Error establishing a database connection?

The problem is I want to log some warning if it happens to api logger.

If no, is there possibility to create one and maybe you could suggest how ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, done a little bit different implementation of the problem fix, without hooks. TC.